# Golang gorilla/sessions and URI scope?

Tags: go

I am still new to Go... This is very strange...

I have a simple web app using Gorilla Sessions for authentication. I am storing a session object Auth in a NewCookieStore.

If I browse to /users, my code 302 redirects to /login. I log in and it works. I can go to /users and then click to /user/1234 just fine.

If I enter /user/1234 directly, it redirects to /login correctly, logs me in, and my UI shows that the Auth variable in the header. But it cannot get the Auth object from the session.

If I flatten the URLs to be /users and /1234, it works correctly...

So it must have something to do with scope and the URI? When I go to the /user/1234, the GetAuth just returns nil. But it returns the correct object one level higher...

Protecting the URIs is done by a middleware func. So the code should be the same either way.

Can someone please point out what I am missing?

Thanks in advance

```
func protect(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Println("-----------------", r.Method, r.RequestURI)

        s := db.GetSession(r)
        auth := db.GetAuth(s)

        if !auth.Authenticated {
            returnuri := r.RequestURI
            s.Values["ReturnURI"] = returnuri
            err := s.Save(r, w)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", 302)
        }

        next(w, r)
    }
}
```

...

```
var Store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("super-secret-key"))

type Auth struct {
    Username      string
    Authenticated bool
}

func InitSessions() {
    Store.Options = &sessions.Options{
        MaxAge:   60 * 5,
        HttpOnly: true,
    }
    gob.Register(Auth{})
}

func GetSession(r *http.Request) *sessions.Session {

    s, err := Store.Get(r, "user-session")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return s
}

func GetAuth(s *sessions.Session) Auth {

    val := s.Values["Auth"]
    var auth = Auth{}
    auth, ok := val.(Auth)
    if !ok {
        auth = Auth{Authenticated: false, Username: ""}
    }
    return auth

}
```

...

```
    if match {
        auth := db.Auth{
            Username:      user.Name,
            Authenticated: true,
        }
        s.Values["Auth"] = auth

        err := s.Save(r, w)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 302)
```

...

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/", logged(handlers.Index))
r.HandleFunc("/signup", logged(handlers.Signup))
r.HandleFunc("/login", logged(handlers.Login))
r.HandleFunc("/logout", logged(handlers.Logout))

r.HandleFunc("/user", protect(handlers.User))
r.HandleFunc("/user/{id}", protect(handlers.User))
r.HandleFunc("/users", protect(handlers.Users))
```

Answer (score 0):

Bingo... Needed the Path option. It must have been using an arbitrary path depending on how I came in...

```
Store.Options = &sessions.Options{
    Path:     "/",
    MaxAge:   60 * 5,
    HttpOnly: true,
}
```